# Convert PHP string to multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string as follow

```
Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
Registry Registrant ID: REDACTED
Registrant Name: REDACTED
Registrant Organization: X
Registrant Street: REDACTED
Registrant City: REDACTED
Registrant State/Province: Western
Registrant Postal Code: REDACTED
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: REDACTED
Registrant Phone Ext: REDACTED
Registrant Fax: REDACTED
Registrant Fax Ext: REDACTED
```

I am trying to convert this string to an array with key/value pairs.  Eg Registrant City as the Key and then REDACTED as the value.

I tried to explode it, but not getting the result at all.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: show us some code

Comment: explode on `:` and create a key value pair of the 2 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way as below

```
$str = 'Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
Registry Registrant ID: REDACTED
Registrant Name: REDACTED
Registrant Organization: X
Registrant Street: REDACTED
Registrant City: REDACTED
Registrant State/Province: Western
Registrant Postal Code: REDACTED
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: REDACTED
Registrant Phone Ext: REDACTED
Registrant Fax: REDACTED
Registrant Fax Ext: REDACTED';

$arr_data = explode("\n", $str);

$arr_final_data = [];
foreach($arr_data as $data){
    $temp_arr = explode(':', $data);
    // If key value pair exist
    if(count($temp_arr) > 1){
        $arr_final_data[trim($temp_arr[0])] = trim($temp_arr[1]);
    }
}
print_r($arr_final_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split into lines, and then split by the colon.  You can shift the first key pair off after if you don't want it.

```
<?php

$data =<<<DATA
Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
Registry Registrant ID: REDACTED
Registrant Name: REDACTED
Registrant Organization: X
Registrant Street: REDACTED
Registrant City: REDACTED
Registrant State/Province: Western
Registrant Postal Code: REDACTED
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: REDACTED
Registrant Phone Ext: REDACTED
Registrant Fax: REDACTED
Registrant Fax Ext: REDACTED
DATA;

$items = preg_split('/\R/', $data);
foreach($items as $line) {
    $pair = explode(': ', $line);
    $result[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Domain Status' => 'ok https://icann.org/epp#ok',
    'Registry Registrant ID' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Name' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Organization' => 'X',
    'Registrant Street' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant City' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant State/Province' => 'Western',
    'Registrant Postal Code' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Country' => 'US',
    'Registrant Phone' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Phone Ext' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Fax' => 'REDACTED',
    'Registrant Fax Ext' => 'REDACTED',
  )
```